# Constructing a matrix from the null space

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

So I need this for a problem I am solving in coding theory. 
Suppose I am working in the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

I know that the $Null(H) = \{(1 1 0 0 1 1),(0 0 1 1 1 1),(0 0 0 0 0 0),(1 1 1 1 0 0)\}$, where H is the matrix I am looking for, so I want now to construct matrix H of size 4x6 that has the nullspace above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathrm{Null}(H)$ is two-dimensional, so $H$ has to have full rank. So let’s start with the approach
$$
 H =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ? & ? \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ? & ? \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & ? & ? \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & ? & ?
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
$\mathrm{Null}(H)$ is generated by $(1,1,1,1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1,1,1,1)$; for these two to be in the nullspace we need the sum of the first four entries of each row and the last four entries of each row to be zero; if we think about the entries as whole numbers, then we need the sums to be even. In the above form this is not possible for $(1,1,1,1,0,0)$, so we slightly change our approach to
$$
 H =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  ? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ? \\
  ? & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ? \\
  ? & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & ? \\
  ? & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & ?
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This form has the advantage that the first colums has no effect on the sum of the last four entries of each row, and the last column has no effect on the sum of the first four entries of each row. Because of this we can now (uniquely) fill in the missing entries to satisfy our conditions and obtain the solution
$$
 H =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

We can work backwards through the usual process of finding a basis for $\text{Null}(H)$:

$\text{dim}(H) = 2$, so pick two linearly independent non-zero vectors and express any element of $\text{Null}(H)$ a linear combination: $\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\\x_6\end{bmatrix}
=c_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}+c_2\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_1\\0\\0\\c_1\\c_1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}c_2\\c_2\\c_2\\c_2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}c_1+c_2\\c_1+c_2\\\phantom{c_1+{}}c_2\\\phantom{c_1+{}}c_2\\c_1\phantom{{}+c_2}\\c_1\phantom{{}+c_2}\end{bmatrix}$.

Assigning the parameters $c_i$ to variables $x_j$ from the bottom up we get:
$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\\x_6\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}x_6+x_4\\x_6+x_4\\\phantom{c_1+{}}x_4\\\phantom{c_1+{}}x_4\\x_6\phantom{{}+c_2}\\x_6\phantom{{}+c_2}\end{bmatrix}$
which corresponds to the matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&-1&0&-1\\0&1&0&-1&0&-1\\0&0&1&-1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1&0&1\\0&1&0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$